# CRM Plugin,system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, linq, plugins, crm

I am creating a CRM plugin that works on case create as a post event.
I deployed the plugin, by the registration tool, enabled sandbox and I choose database as store location for the assembly. 
Note: I am using CRM 2015 online.

The following error popped up:

`Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): cases_plugin.casereserve: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.`

---

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Xrm;

namespace cases_plugin
{
    public class casereserve : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            int count = 0;
            int min = 100000000;
            var xrm = new XrmServiceContext("Xrm");

            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
            (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            Entity targetEntity = null;
             if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
             {
                 targetEntity = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
                 if (context.MessageName != "Create")
                     return;
                 if (context.PrimaryEntityName != "incident")
                     return;
             }
            Incident currentcase = targetEntity.ToEntity<Incident>();
            SystemUser useruse= new SystemUser();
            var users = from user in xrm.SystemUserSet where user.new_CaseTypeResponsipelty ==currentcase.CaseTypeCode select user;
            foreach (var useritm in users)
            {
                var caseno = from cases in xrm.IncidentSet where cases.OwningUser.Id == useritm.Id && (cases.StatusCode == 5 || cases.StatusCode == 1000 || cases.StatusCode == 6 || cases.StatusCode == 2000) select cases;
                foreach (var caseitm in caseno)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count < min)
                {
                    min = count;
                    useruse.Id = useritm.Id;
                    useruse.FirstName = useritm.FirstName;
                }
                count = 0;
            }


            AssignRequest assign = new AssignRequest
            {
                Assignee = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName,
                    useruse.Id),
                Target = new EntityReference(Incident.EntityLogicalName,
                    currentcase.Id)
            };

            xrm.Execute(assign);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove reference to Microsoft.Xrm.Client assembly.

Comment: Hi Andrii, I am using early bound classes which requires that assembly reference.

Comment: I believe you've missed something. Following article  -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 states that Microsoft.Xrm.Client assembly is not required for usage of Early Bound classes:
The following lists assemblies that must be referenced in your project when you use the generated code file.

    Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll

    Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll

Comment: Thanks man I solved the problem by removing the CodeCustomization from the cmd command 


CrmSvcUtil.exe /codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration" /out:Xrm.cs /url:########/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc /username:####### /password:######## /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
now Xrm.client is not required :)